# How to get key from object in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using this to get object from Key

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *object=[defaults objectForKey:someKey];
```

How I can get opposite effect? Key from Object?
Something like

```
NSString *key=[defaults keyForObject:object];
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you going to do this? I think, it's not good idea to get key for object from user defaults (even if it possible). NSUserDefaults class usually uses for storing settings of application.

Comment: Because I'm storing some small information. And need to read it back , both keys, and objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `NSUserDefaults` dictionary (with the `dictionaryRepresentation` method). You can then use the dictionary method

```
- (NSSet *)keysOfEntriesPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

or

```
- (NSArray *)allKeysForObject:(id)anObject
```

to get the key for your object.